# disabling deprecated errors

Tags: php

I want to enable deprecated errors globally but disable them for a specific piece of third-party code, which I don't have the time to fix.
So, I have this in php.ini:
    `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED`

and this right before the line where I want to disable the warnings
    `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

However, it does not work, I'm still getting the warnings for that particular line. If I disable them globally in php.ini it works. I'm using PHP 5.3.10. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: How do you disable them in php.ini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The third party code has custom error handler and apparently it's overriding anything you set with error_reporting(). When I commented out the set_error_handler() line, error_reporting() took effect.

Comment: So mark your answer as solution, so that this question gets solved.

Comment: I tried. It says I must wait 2 days before marking it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below error reporting line in your php.ini:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Then restart your server and check it.