# Suppress an error from the logs too

Tags: php, mysql, suppress-warnings

CodeIgniter 2.x still uses the classic `mysql`. We all know it's bad practice to still use it, but my job still requires me to use CodeIgniter.

I always have my Console.app (OSX) open watching my Apache/MySQL/PHP/CodeIgniter-native error logs.

Now I mostly have all notices/errors/etc. fixed always instantly when I see them and constantly monitor my development with Webgrind on my MAMP.

Back to the start; I constantly have one big annoying thing each page-load PHP always gives the error about `mysql_pconnect` is going to get deprecated in the future.

In the CodeIgniter driver the command is suppressed by `@` to not print the warnings to the screen, but it still ends up in my logs.

Is there any viable way to except one such error specifically in either PHP code or the PHP settings?

Locally I could recompile the whole PHP core and just remove the warning, but I would like to have the logs on our production installations rid of those warnings too :P.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, you can use set error verbosity using `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED)` (i.e., report everything—except notices and deprecation warnings) as mentioned in ["disabling deprecated errors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218945/disabling-deprecated-errors).

Your issue may be related to CodeIgniter taking ownership of all errors.

[system/core/CodeIgniter.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/e17ccdb9cefa21df944b416a5461661419263ad0/system/core/CodeIgniter.php) calls the function `set_error_handler`. You can find and modify the function `_exception_handler` it invokes on error in [system/core/Common.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2b284f9b171ba0e0886db15772a6a62e9155f74f/system/core/Common.php). It doesn't appear to be a configurable, so you may simply want to edit the line that begins with `$is_error`.

Comment: Thanks for info Jacob. I've added a custom `$message` match on full-string in the `_exception_handler` so it will just skip logging for that exact error. Finally clean logs, thank you!